# How to tell yum that a package is installed when it thinks it isn't?

Tags: fedora, yum

I accidentally deleted all my RPM data (I removed `/var/lib/rpm/*` instead of `/var/lib/rpm/__*`), and then ran `rpm --rebuilddb`. Now when I try to run `yum update` I get:

```
Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org
/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=i386 error was
No repomd file
Error: File /var/cache/yum/i386/$releasever/fedora/metalink.xml does 
not exist
```

I found that I don't even have the `/var/cache/yum/i386` folder anymore after the previous operation. I downloaded the fedora-release RPM of Fedora 18 and locally installed and rebuilt my yum cache (is that what i did?):

```
rpm -Uvh --replacefiles --replacepkgs /$MYPATH_TO_Fedorareles/fedorarelease-18-0.8.noarch.rpm
```

This made a new rpmdb where only one package is installed: `fedora-release`. Since yum thinks that's the only package installed, if I try to install anything it resolves the dependencies and queues lots of packages for install that I actually already have installed.

How do I make yum aware of all the packages that are already installed? I don't want to reinstall anything, and I don't want to download 500MB of RPMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you are going to have to repopulate the rpmdb, and you can only do that if you have the RPMs itself. You can pass `--justdb` to `rpm` when performing a package install/update/erase, but you will need the actual package available.

Comment: Just make _absolutely_ sure that the packages really are there.